# Get entity by properties entity framework 4.1

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I am wondering how to get an entity by properties

I don’t want to use SqlQuery method where you pass actual SQL query.  Find() work with PK values only.

I want to be able to have a method in my repository where I can pass in a dictionary of property with respective value to filter my entities.

```
public IList<TEntity> FindByProperties(IDictionary<string,object> propertyValues)
```

NHibernate provides criteria query api, is there anything similar in EF?

Please suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Entity Framework normally you use *lambda expressions* to create filter criteria. You could have a method...

```cs
public IList<TEntity> FindByExpression(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter)
{
    return context.Set<TEntity>().Where(filter).ToList();
}
```

...and call it like so:

```cs
...FindByExpression(t => t.Name == "Jim" && t.City == "Paris");
```